# What happens when keeping assigning a variable with different constant tensors in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Environment: Keras 2.2.5, TensorFlow 1.12.0 backend

I typed the following codes in a terminal, noticing that the number in the name of the assigned variable kept increasing. Since tf 1.x uses static graph, I doubted that the tensors created in this process would exist until I reset the default graph with `K.clear_session()` . Was my guess right? Or the garbage collector destroys the tensors automatically?

```
>>> import keras.backend as K
>>> a = K.constant(1.0)
>>> a = K.constant(2.0)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
>>> b = K.constant(2.2)
>>> b
<tf.Tensor 'Const_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
>>> a = K.constant(222.1)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Const_3:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
>>> a = K.constant(222.1)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Const_4:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right; tensors are *persistent* until session is cleared. Simple demo:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

a = K.constant(1.0)
print(a)      # Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
print(a.name) # Const:0
del a

a = K.constant(1.0)
print(a)      # Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Despite `del a`, the new tensor's name is still incremented: `Const_1:0`. But what if the session simply 'memorized' (e.g. cached) the first creation via `K.constant`, so it increments the *name* even though the previous tensor was deleted? Nope - this can be verified:

```py
print(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Const:0"))
# Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

It's still there. Unlike regular Python objects, which are deleted after reference count reaches zero, Tensor objects persist (the graph sets up *its own* references). To fully delete the tensor (and all other tensors), you'll need two commands:

```py
K.clear_session()  # clear Keras graph
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()  # clear TF graph
```

(*Sometimes* the first one suffices, but best to use both). Trying  to access the tensor now:

```py
print(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Const:0"))
# KeyError: "The name 'Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. 
# The operation, 'Const', does not exist in the graph."
```

Creating a new one:

```py
a = K.constant(1.0)
print(a)  # Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The tensors created in this process would exist until I reset the default graph with K.clear_session()

That is correct in Tensorflow each variable name will be unique. 

Example:

```
b = K.constant(1)
print(b)
b = K.constant(1)
print(b)
K.clear_session()
b = K.constant(1)
print(b)
# output
# Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
# Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
# Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Although you can have same variable name in different scope.
Example

```
with tf.variable_scope("scope1"):
    a = K.constant(1)
    print(a)
with tf.variable_scope("scope2"):
    a = K.constant([1,2])
    print(a)
# output
# Tensor("scope1/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
# Tensor("scope2/Const:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

> The garbage collector destroys the tensors automatically?

No Python garbage collector will not remove TensorFlow variables. You'll have to clear session manually.