# Remove tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor on model save

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm passing `gpu_mem = tf.contrib.memory_stats.MaxBytesInUse() / (2 ** 30)` to `sess.run`, but on model save I want to delete `gpu_mem` (tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor) from graph, is it possible?

The point of deleting this tensor is that when model is loaded on CPU it produce an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1339, in _run_fn
    self._extend_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _extend_graph
    tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'MaxBytesInUse' used by {{node MaxBytesInUse}}with these attrs: []
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'

     [[MaxBytesInUse]]
```

Comment: Tensors are [persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888267/what-happens-when-keeping-assigning-a-variable-with-different-constant-tensors-i/58888716#58888716), and deletion would require cutting all graph references to set Python object reference to zero for garbage collection; even if accomplished, it may not be the best idea to hack away a graph element this way especially for saving. What is your goal with deleting `gpu_mem` - is there an error? And is your model a `tf.keras` instance?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Updated, no I use tensorflow model.

Comment: Don't know how you'd circumvent this, but you should probably not rely on a solution in deleting the tensor; run `import gc;` `print(gc.get_referrers(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(gpu_mem._name)))` -- you'd have to delete all the referrers while not messing up the graph. I suggest opening an issue on Github

Comment: How do you save and load your model?